# Shnayim Mikrah V'Echad Targum

Tags: tzibur-community, parsha-torah-portion, shnayim-mikra

If one is behind in his reading of *Shnayim Mikrah* , but isn't in the middle of a *Parsha* , may he skip to the current week's to be with the *Tzibbur?* ( sources are appreciated )